# Menu Bar Height in the LWUIT Form

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, samsung-mobile

Application develop in the J2ME using LWUIT. When I port this application on the Samsung Device it create the following problem.

`int h = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();`

It returns 388 for the Samsung GT S5250. So when I draw an image using this dimension it displays a white strip at the bottom of the screen. When I call the `Form.show()` it displays correctly and height is 400 so how to resolve this issue.
I want to know how the `Form` size is calculated in LWUIT and how it takes `MenuBar` Height and white strip display at bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you typed `getDisplayWidth()` where you meant to type `getDisplayHeight()`.

Regardless, the problem you are seeing is due to a bug in the samsung device. LWUIT invokes the full screen mode in MIDP which hides the native title area, however that doesn't always happen immediately in some devices and thus LWUIT gets incorrect information from the devices. A refresh usually solves this and by the time LWUIT draws on the screen the size is corrected.

Generally the solution is rather simple, create generic code to create your image and if the image dimensions are inappropriate when you are about to draw to the screen then just recreate the image on the fly. This will also solve the issue of device rotation which might pose a problem too.

Comment: Hi.when i not add an image to the form then also at bottom of the Screen white strip is displaying.how to remove this strip.i just set the background color of the Form.i also add canvas.servicesReapint(); but it not effect anything.how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Don't call serviceRepaints. You didn't specify how you added the image to the form? You should write your code within the callSerially end method which means that LWUIT had time to initialize the screen properly. I suggest you have a look at the LWUIT 1.5 demos which start LWUIT on a callSerially callback.